# Why does Google Cloud Functions return Error: could not handle the request?

Tags: python, http, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I have a GCF in Python to refresh an access token each 9 hours.
When I test the function I get a Response 200, success!

But when I send POST requests or try to call the function via Google Scheduler I got an error `Error: could not handle the request` on the first 3 or more times. After send a couple of requests the function is executed. Why?

[image: Scheduler configuration]

My function below:

```
from os import getenv
import requests
import pymysql
import json
from pymysql.err import OperationalError


CONNECTION_NAME = getenv('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME', '')
DB_USER = getenv('MYSQL_USER', '')
DB_PASSWORD = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '')
DB_NAME = getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE', '')

mysql_config = {
  'user': DB_USER,
  'password': DB_PASSWORD,
  'db': DB_NAME,
  'charset': 'utf8mb4',
  'cursorclass': pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
  'autocommit': True
}

mysql_conn = None


def __get_cursor():
    try:
        return mysql_conn.cursor()
    except OperationalError:
        mysql_conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        return mysql_conn.cursor()


def authMonzo(request):
    global mysql_conn
    global endpoint

    endpoint = ''

    if not mysql_conn:
        try:
            mysql_conn = pymysql.connect(**mysql_config)
        except OperationalError:
            mysql_config['unix_socket'] = f'/cloudsql/{CONNECTION_NAME}'
            mysql_conn = pymysql.connect(**mysql_config)

    with __get_cursor() as cursor:   
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TOKENS ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        clientSecret = result[...]
        clientId = result[...]
        refreshToken = result[...]

        # Change the last refresh token for a new access token
        tokenRequest = requests.post(endpoint, data={'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'client_id': clientId, 'client_secret': clientSecret, 'refresh_token': refreshToken})
        tokenJson = json.loads(tokenRequest.content)

        print(tokenJson)

        # Assing the values to variables
        accessToken = tokenJson['access_token']
        refreshToken = tokenJson['refresh_token']
        scope = tokenJson['scope']
        clientId = tokenJson['client_id']
        expiresIn = tokenJson['expires_in']
        userId = tokenJson['user_id']
        tokenType = tokenJson['token_type']

        # Insert the new token on the table tokens
        SQLToken = ("INSERT INTO TOKENS (CLIENT_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN, TOKEN_TYPE, USER_ID, CLIENT_ID, EXPIRES_IN, SCOPE) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
        Values = (clientSecret, accessToken, refreshToken, tokenType, userId, clientId, expiresIn, scope)

        cursor.execute(SQLToken, Values)
        mysql_conn.close()

    return str(accessToken)
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the error?  Which component of GCP is logging the error?  Are there additional diagnostics available in Stackdriver Logging?

Comment: @Kolban the error occurs when I call the function via Scheduler or via HTTP (Postman for example)

Comment: @Marcelo Gazzola - How are you making the postman call authenticated? Meaning the rest call client should be authenticated to GCP project before you can place a request.